# ListView jumps to top after adding data to first index

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I have an app that fetch comments from a website, it has a listview with prepopulated data on initState. I have also included a library to do swipe to refresh. When i do a "swipe to refresh", i am fetching the older comments and this will be added to the top of the list(index 0) but i want the user to stay at his current position. Right now it is jumping to the start of the updated comment list after the older comments are fetched. Ideally, I want the user to stay at his current position and scroll up to view older comments.

**Sample code:**

```
ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
List<String> commentList = new List();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initListView();
}

_initListView(){
 for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
    commentList.add("Test Comment" + i.toString);
 }

_loadPreviousPageData(){
  await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2));
  //some http get functionality here

  for(int i = 5; i>=0; i--){
    setState(() {
      commentList.insert(0, "Test Previous Comment: " + index);
    });

  }

  _scrollController.jumpTo(//insert something here);
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
        body: new Expanded(
          child: new RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _loadPreviousPageData,
            child: new ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: commentList.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                  return new Text(commentList[index]);
               }
            )
         )
      )
   );
}
```

Link to gif:
https://i.imgur.com/pZ8jPwe.gifv

Comment: What do you mean? When you swipe at the top to refresh, you will always be at 0 somehow, before refreshing.

Comment: Sorry if it's hard to understand, before I refresh i wiil be at position 0 so that I can "swipe to refresh". But once the data is fetched, let's say 5 new data is added from index 0, I want to stay at position 5. But instead I got jumped to position 0.

Comment: @FadhliS so basically you want to append data to end of the list?

Comment: @VidorVistrom I want to append data to the start of the list (index 0) but i dont want to jump to the new index 0. Instead i want to stay at my current position.

Comment: I have added a link to a screenshot if it helps. I cant post any image.

Comment: I still don’t get it. When you refresh you will always be at the top regardless of having new data or not. Jumping back to bottom or somewhere else after refreshing, isn’t actually the most desired UX behavior and IMO will look like a bug instead, however, it’s possible.

Comment: @miguelpruivo I shall explain what my app does.I am fetching comments from a website. When i do a "swipe to refresh", i am fetching the older comments and this will be added to the top of the list but i want the user to stay at his current position, not jump to the start of the updated comment list after the older comments are fetched. Similar to how facebook comments is fetched when u load older comments.

Comment: You don’t have to pull to refresh comments with Facebook. It’s been using load on scroll for a while. Maybe edit your question with a gif of what you want.

Comment: @miguelpruivo Thanks, i have edited my question. I have also added a gif screenshot of what it should look like.

Comment: So, basically, you are at one page that when refreshes a new content appears above and now below and you want to stay in the same list item, is it that?

Comment: @miguelpruivo yup yup i want to stay at same list item. Before i refresh i was at index 0. After 5 comments are fetched for example,  i should stay at index 5